# running Gstreamer video embedded in GTK window under Weston

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gstreamer, wayland

I am testing Gstreamer Waylandsink example, which is a Gstreamer testing video embedded into GTK window running on top of Weston:
https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/master/tests/examples/waylandsink

More description of my problem here with backtrace also:
http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Waylandsink-segmentation-fault-td4691887.html
http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/GstVideoOverlay-td4691869.html
http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/gst-video-overlay-set-render-rectangle-td4691801.html

The window opens properly and is running video example, but upon button
click (button NULL), I want to erase the video rendering area I have created. According to documentation of method gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle, it should close the rendering area:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/gstvideooverlay.html?gi-language=c

therefore I added this piece of code:

```
null_clicked_cb (GtkButton * button, DemoApp * d)
    {
    GtkAllocation allocation;
      gtk_widget_get_allocation(d->video_widget,&allocation);
      GstWaylandSink *sink = GST_WAYLAND_SINK (d->overlay);
      GstVideoOverlay* overlay;
      overlay = d->overlay;
      gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle (overlay, allocation.x,allocation.y, -1, -1);        
}
```

I am feeding the method with these values: x 26 y 60 width -1 height -1
I got randomly one of these errors under Weston:
Gdk-message: Error reading events from display: Protocol error
Gdk-message: Error 32 (Broken-pipe) displatching to Wayland display
Gdk-message: error flushing display

I got this error in Wayland Gnome shell:

```
0:00:02.355175744 25457 0x5641c5dd4150 ERROR               fdmemory
gstfdmemory.c:127:gst_fd_mem_map: 0x7f9edc00b680: fd 17: mmap failed: Cannot
allocate memory
0:00:02.355213222 25457 0x5641c5dd4150 ERROR            waylandsink
wlshmallocator.c:78:gst_wl_shm_allocator_alloc:<wlshmallocator0> GstFdMemory
map failed
0:00:02.355238267 25457 0x5641c5dd4150 WARN              GST_BUFFER
gstbuffer.c:907:gst_buffer_new_allocate: failed to allocate
5680698421285089536 bytes

(waylandexample:25457): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 22:03:17.493:
gst_buffer_memset: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer)' failed

(waylandexample:25457): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 22:03:17.493:
gst_buffer_peek_memory: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer)' failed
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to get rid of the error message popping while using method:
gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle()
It works only when using playbin and sink waylandsink, If I use pipeline with videotestsrc, it stops at this method yielding before mentioned errors.
Unfortunately the problem with black sub window (which causes fullscreen video to be rendered only partially) still remains even though I thought I cleared all the rendering sub windows clearing the screen for single video to be rendered full screen (actually "full window" as videos are running in single GTK window)
I assumed that calling  gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle() on three remaining window handles will clear the area unfortunately black rectangle randomly remains on some of the areas where the other videos where rendered.
I am enclosing the entire button click method with all my attempts to hide (clear, disable or how should I name it) in comments.

```
static void button_press_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, DemoApp * d) {

if (destroy == FALSE) {
   gtk_widget_get_allocation(d->video_widget1, &allocation);
    GstStateChangeReturn state;
    //state = gst_element_set_state(d->pipeline0, GST_STATE_NULL);
    //g_print("pipeline state:%d\r\n", state);
    state = gst_element_set_state(d->pipeline1, GST_STATE_NULL);
    g_print("pipeline state:%d\r\n", state);
    state = gst_element_set_state(d->pipeline2, GST_STATE_NULL);
    g_print("pipeline state:%d\r\n", state);
    state = gst_element_set_state(d->pipeline3, GST_STATE_NULL);
    g_print("pipeline state:%d\r\n", state);
   /*
    gboolean result = gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle(d->overlay1, -1,
            -1, -1, -1);
     */
    gboolean result = FALSE;

    gtk_widget_get_allocation(d->video_widget0, &allocation);

    result = gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle(d->overlay0, allocation.x,
            allocation.y, -1, -1);
    g_print("x=%d,y=%d,width=%d,height=%d, result=%d\r\n", allocation.x, allocation.y, allocation.width, allocation.height, result);

    gtk_widget_get_allocation(d->video_widget1, &allocation);
    result = FALSE;
    result = gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle(d->overlay1, allocation.x,
            allocation.y, -1, -1);
    g_print("x=%d,y=%d,width=%d,height=%d, result=%d\r\n", allocation.x, allocation.y, allocation.width, allocation.height, result);
   // gst_object_unref(d->overlay1);

    gtk_widget_get_allocation(d->video_widget2, &allocation);
    result = FALSE;
    result = gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle(d->overlay2, allocation.x,
            allocation.y, -1, -1);
    g_print("x=%d,y=%d,width=%d,height=%d, result=%d\r\n", allocation.x, allocation.y, allocation.width, allocation.height, result);
    //gst_object_unref(d->overlay2);


    gtk_widget_get_allocation(d->video_widget3, &allocation);
    result = FALSE;
    result = gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle(d->overlay3, allocation.x,
            allocation.y, -1, -1);
    g_print("x=%d,y=%d,width=%d,height=%d, result=%d\r\n", allocation.x, allocation.y, allocation.width, allocation.height, result);
    //gst_object_unref(d->overlay3);
    /*
            gst_video_overlay_expose(d->overlay0);
            gst_video_overlay_expose(d->overlay1);
            gst_video_overlay_expose(d->overlay2);
            gst_video_overlay_expose(d->overlay3);
     */
    /*
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(d->overlay1, (guintptr) 0);
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(d->overlay2, (guintptr) 0);
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(d->overlay2, (guintptr) 0);
     */
    gtk_widget_set_visible(d->video_widget1, FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_visible(d->video_widget2, FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_visible(d->video_widget3, FALSE);

    //gst_video_overlay_expose(d->overlay1);

    //g_print("result=%d\r\n", result);
    int width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(d->videoElementsGrid);
    int height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(d->videoElementsGrid);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(d->video_widget0, width, height);
    gtk_widget_get_allocation(d->video_widget0, &allocation);
    struct wl_surface *window_handle = gdk_wayland_window_get_wl_surface(gtk_widget_get_window(d->video_widget0));
    wl_surface_damage_buffer(window_handle,allocation.x,allocation.y,width,height);
    //gst_element_set_state(d->pipeline0, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    destroy = TRUE;
} else {
```